# Add exclude to TaskInputs from pre-defined task

Tags: gradle

In a project that I am converting to Gradle, we run tests from within the `resources/test` directory.  Some of the tests produce log files that are output into that directory.  In the projects that do this, every time I run `gradle build` the up-to-date check for the `test` task fails because the log files have a different contents from the previous time the task was run.

I want to remove just the log files from the `TaskInputs` object defined for the auto-generated `test` task from the `java` plugin.

---

I managed to find where in the TaskInputs the `resources/test` is defined and figured out how to build a replacement item that excludes the log files, but it turns out that I can't modify the `sourceCollections` property.

```
    test {
        def modified = inputs.files.sourceCollections.collect {
             if (it.displayName.contains("resources${File.separator}test"))
             {
                 p.fileTree(dir: it.asPath, exclude: '*.log')
             }
             else
             {
                 it
             }
        }
        // this produces an error as this is a read-only property
        inputs.files.sourceCollections = modified
    }
```

---

Is there a way that I can force the log files to be excluded from the TaskInputs?

---

***Edit***: I tried another approach of filtering the files property, but it appears to have no effect.

```
    test {
        inputs.files.filter {
            exclude '*.log'
        }
        inputs.sourceFiles.filter {
            exclude '*.log'
        }
    }
```

---

***Edit2***: I tried another approach and seem to be getting somewhere:

```
    test {
        inputs.sourceFiles.filter {
            !it.name.endsWith("resources${File.separator}test")
        }
        inputs.sourceDir p.fileTree(dir: p.sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir, exclude: '*.log')
    }
```

When I do this, I can print off the contents of `inputs.sourceFiles` and see that the log files are not part of the listing, but the task still triggers because the log files have changed.

Comment: `sourceFiles.filter` creates a new collection. I'm not aware of a public API that allows to remove (rather than add) input files. Perhaps you can fix the tests?

Comment: Where should the tests output their logging?  We don't want to turn off the logging for the tests.  I'm still trying to learn all of the Gradle conventions, but I'm not aware of any separation between test input (test/resources) and where tests are supposed to write data.

Comment: I suppose you mean `build/test/resources`. Tests shouldn't write to this directory, but to some other directory that they own.